# BIDI equivalent of left and right CSS properties

Tags: css, right-to-left, bidi

I want to place an element in bottom left corner of another, element. I give `position:relative` to the parent, and `position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0` to the child.

The problem is that the page can be loaded in ltr or rtl. In case of RTL, the child element has to be in the bottom *right* corner of the parent.

Many CSS properties have bidi equivalents, such as `margin-left` goes to `margin-inline-end`. Is there a bidi equivalent of `left` CSS property

Comment: no & yes, if you use flex or grid, then you can tell to align start/end .  Share enough code to show your issue , so we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

MDN points to [`inset-inline-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset-inline-start) as logical equivalent of left